# Iterate dictionary to make new dictionary with string values in them

Tags: c#, dictionary

I need to iterate dictionary and make new dictionary object from it. If the value of dictionary is integer then I want to populate keys and values into new dictionary object.
Basically idea is make a new dictionary object which only contains keys and integer values. If there is any string values then I don't want to add those keys and values in it.

I tried like this but I wanted to see if there is any better way of doing this. I might be doing something wrong which is inaccurate so wanted to see if there is any better way.

```
public override object Save(IDictionary<string, object> value)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> newValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach(var entry in value)
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse((string)entry.Value, out var id))
        {
            newValues.Add(entry.Key, id);
        }
    }
    return base.Process(newValues);
}
```

Comment: if you're not going to inspect the type of the Value, at least you'll need to kludge it with `entry.ToString` rather than casting to string .. can't cast `123` to string but you can parse `"123"`

Comment: You mean `entry.Value.ToString`?

Comment: Yes. So, tell us more about what kind of values are in this dictionary. Are they just bits and strings? What do the strings look like? Any numerical ones? Are you supposed to keep those too or just the true ints?

Comment: Values can be number or number string or string string. I want to keep all the numbers whether they are number or number strings. @CaiusJard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you've had a bunch of answers.. but they're all so far either not quite there or not really an improvement on what you have (if you make the change mentioned in the comments..)

An alternative to what you have, using linq, would be:

Let's select every keyvaluepair and try and parse its value. If it parses, return an anonymous type that includes the Key and the parsed value, otherwise return null. Then let's exclude the nulls and turn it into a dictionary

```
 return base.Process(
   value.Select(kvp => int.TryParse(kvp.Value.ToString(), out var Val) ?  new { kvp.Key, Val } : null)
     .Where(x => x != null)
     .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Val)
 );
```

But genuinely, it's effectively the same as what you have, except it's more compact but slower because it loops more.. and it's harder to understand.

---

If you're after literally just filtering the existing dictionary based on whether the entry's value is int flavored, but keeping it as-is:

```
 return base.Process(
   value
     .Where(kvp => kvp.Value is int || (kvp.Value is string s && int.TryParse(s, out var _)))
     .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value)
 );
```

---

Another alternative could be to not prepare a new dictionary at all, but just remove bad values from the one you have

```
public override object Save(IDictionary<string, object> value)
{
    var toRemove = new List<string>(values.Count);
    foreach(var entry in value)
        if (entry.Value is string s && !int.TryParse(s, out var _))
            toRemove.Add(entry.Key);

    toRemove.ForEach(s => value.Remove(s));

    return base.Process(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is unsafe! This is because the cast to string may throw an exception. A better approach would be to check the type:

```
foreach(var i in dictionary) {

    if(i.Value is String str && int.TryParse(str, out int intValue)) {
       newValues.Add(i.Key, intValue);
    }
    else if (i.Value is int) {
       newValues.Add(i.Key, i.Value);
    }
}
```

You may add more control flows to also capture other kinds of numeric values such as doubles, decimals, floats, etc. followed by converting them to `int`.

You can change the order of the control flow for performance tuning.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. In my case values can be number or number string or string string. I want to keep all the numbers whether they are number or number strings.

Comment: @AndyP I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 var id=0;
 IDictionary<string, int> newValues =value
   .Where(p => Int32.TryParse(p.Value.ToString(), out id))
   .ToDictionary(p => p.Key,
                 p => id
     );
```

or if you want object

```
var id=0;
 IDictionary<string, object> newValues =    myDictionary
   .Where(p => Int32.TryParse(p.Value.ToString(), out id))
   .ToDictionary(p => p.Key,
                 p => (object)id
    );
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a LINQ solution,

```
public override object Save(IDictionary<string, object> value)
{
    return base.Process(value.Where(v => int.TryParse(v.Value as string, out var _)));
}
```

Comment: Eric, `v.Value as string` would fail in case there is an integer present rather than a `string`. I guess this is what the OP is looking for, getting both `int`s and `string`s.

Comment: Furthermore, your code still returns the string! Actually where the value is string and it can be parsed as int.

Comment: @Transcendent It does not fail if Value is not a string. `.Value as string` results in `null` if a cast is not possible. `int.TryParse(null, out _)` returns false.

Comment: The code returns a filtered `IDictionary<string, object>`, exactly as the OP has in the original implementation.